# attributeError：DecisionTreeClassifier object has no attribute

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

And this is my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier (random_state=5,criterion=‘gini’, splutter=‘random’)
clf = clf.fit(train_X,train_Y)
prediction  = clf.prediction_proba(test_X)[:,1]
```

Output is that:

> DecisionTreeClassifier object has no attribute prediction_proba

Can anybody solve this prob?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is `predict_proba` not `prediction_proba`

Comment: okay i gottchu appreciate that!!! i got the result